# Using FPDI AND FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I'm trying to use FPDI and FPDF for generating a pdf, but I have a problem when I create a cell. I want to use the fillcolor. So the Cell has a background color.

For now I have like this:

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php'); 
require_once('pdf/fpdi.php'); 
$pdf = new FPDI();

$pdf->AddPage(); 

$pdf->setSourceFile('anolis_dopis_a4.pdf'); 
// import page 1 
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1); 
//use the imported page and place it at point 0,0; calculate width and height
//automaticallay and ajust the page size to the size of the imported page 
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0, 0, true); 

// now write some text above the imported page 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', '13'); 
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
//set position in pdf document
$pdf->SetXY(40, 50);
//first parameter defines the line height
$pdf->Write(0, 'gift code');

$pdf->SetXY(40, 55);
$pdf->Write(0, 'gift code');

//HERE I WANT TO HAVE BACKGROUND COLOR
$pdf->Cell(100,10,"bla bla",1,"left","");

//force the browser to download the output
$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'D');

?>
```

Comment: worked for me only using Nulls in $x & $y
`$outPdf->useTemplate($outPdf->importPage($i), null, null, 0, 0, true);`. Otherwise It cuts Pages to A4.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem. I found the answer in another topic on this website.

The solution is adding `$pdf->setPageMark();` after the `$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0, 0, true);`

There are probably more people like me out there who have the same problem and end up here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf->SetFillColor(227,227,227);
$pdf->Cell(100,10,'bla bla',1,0,'L',TRUE);
```

Comment: I want to write on pdf Table, but the evry second coll must have backgorund color.

Comment: up example for me works, look at manual for cell - http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm